# Update stock quantities via magento SOAP API v2 in C#

Tags: api, soap, stock

This an old question from the old Magento forum (http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/513702/#top).

I am trying to update stock quantities via magento API method (cataloginventory_stock_item.update) on my application in C#.

The callReturn I get is “true” - which means it updated successfully.

However when I go to the store and check the inventory qty value, I only get the first digit of the value I posted.
For example, when I posted with qty = 80 (or 876 or 8123), I got a stock qty of only 8.

Why am I getting only the first digit through ?

Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you already do some debugging in your store, which value is actually received in the update method of age_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item_Api? Check $data['qty'] and the value in there.